# iOS using color animation button click not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have a question about the iOS in Objective-c.

I try to add the background color animation .

Animation is working properly but my button action is not getting called.

How to fix that? Thank you very much.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.89 green:0.10 blue:0.220 alpha:1.000]];
      [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:3.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
          [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:148/255.0 green:28/255.0 blue:81/255.0 alpha:1]];
      } completion:nil];

 }


 - (IBAction)btnPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
     NSLog(@"button click action");
 }
```

Comment: your question is not able to understand

Comment: I need to achieve the color change in background repeat, But when I add the code, my button action is not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` to allow user interactions during animation :

```
 [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:3.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
     [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:148/255.0 green:28/255.0 blue:81/255.0 alpha:1]];
 } completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! When I add the  "UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction" key , it's can work.